# Javascript unittesting frameworks

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, unit-testing

I am loooking for a javascript unittesing framework and trying to decide if I should go with JSunit or not. My goal is to have the unittests run with my CI, possibly using a JSunit server that is running headless.

From people's experience, is this a good idea? Are there better frameworks that you would recommend for my goals, over JSunit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) is worth reviewing

Comment: Thanks, it looks pretty awesome. What's more using HTMLUnit I can kick of the QUnit tests through Junit, so it looks pretty easy to integrate with our existing CI :D.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your requirements. If you are going to have to test DOM intensive code and need your tests put in separate pages and organized in suites I would recommend using JSUnit. It has a nice test runner, supports suites and fixtures as separate pages. The experience is much like any other xUnit framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JS Unit Test](http://jsunittest.com/), *not JS Unit*, in an automated test environment, but it was run through Selenium. Using [env.js](http://www.envjs.com/) or [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) you can create headless tests with most any JS unit testing library.

Personally I don't go headless.  A headless browser is often an "ideal" browser and might not catch all those browser quirks.  So I ultimately run my browser tests through a browser using Selenium. I use the [Sauce Labs jar.](http://github.com/saucelabs/saucelenium)

For other testing frameworks is a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript), [Screw Unit](http://github.com/nkallen/screw-unit) looks nice if you like BDD.